# Spring boot disable SpringapplicationShutdownhook DEBUG logs

Tags: spring-boot, log4j

I have a batch job which prints below logs

```
SpringApplicationShutdownHook DEBUG Stopped LoggerContext[name=34d0a865, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@dky 3242ax] with status true SpringApplicationShutdownHook DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.Builtconfiguration@vcfald OK
SpringApplicationShutdowntHook DEBUG Appender rolling stopped with status true
SpringApplicationShutdownHook DEBUG Shut down RollingFileManager null/logs/ip-48-164-21-246.ec2.internal/TransactionLog.log, all resources released: true
SpringApplicationShutdownHook DEBUG RollingFileManager shutdown completed with status true SpringApplicationShutdown look DEBUG All asynchronous threads have terminated
SpringApplicationShutdownHook DEBUG OutputStream closed
```

Is there a way to disable this logs using application.properties.
I have set logginglevel to INFO still the DEBUG logs are getting printed.

Comment: These are issued by Log4j's **status** logger, a special logger that prints the status of the logging system on stderr. The level of the status logger can be set in the configuration: can you add your Log4j2 configuration to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a way, so posting it

```
logging.register-shutdown-hook=false
```